# How many keys can be contained at leaf level in B+ Tree

Tags: tree, computer-science, delete-row, b-tree, tree-balancing

In my database class, my professor was describing about deleting keys from the B+ Tree. If you see the below image:

[image]

[image]

I totally understood everything except one part where he told that the `leaf level` nodes can only contain `3` keys at most. As my per my understanding, depending upon the depth of `B+ tree`,  the total keys are decided at the leaf level varies from `d` to `2*d` where d is the depth of tree. Since here `d` for leaf is 2, why can't the leaf level nodes have `4` keys. Where I am going wrong?

The total number of keys contained at the root level also matter here? Could anyone please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I totally understood everything except one part where he told that the leaf level nodes can only contain 3 keys at most.

If he really said that, he's wrong. It is 4, same as the order of the B+-tree. His own picture proves it: see the bottom right-hand node.

> As my per my understanding, depending upon the depth of B+ tree, the total keys are decided at the leaf level varies from d to 2*d where d is the depth of tree

Totally wrong. The depth of the tree has nothing to do with it. The number of keys per node is between N/2 and N, except in the root node which can have fewer.

Comment: Simple and very effective. Thank you sir :)

Comment: How did you calculated order of a B+ tree here? Is it number of elements in the root,  for example here the number of elements is `4`.

Comment: @python You *don't* calculate it. You *specify* it, in your design. The order of a tree is the maximum number of elements that can exist in a node, by design.